# CSS3 easing Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile-safari

How do I recreate the easing/friction for touch events in Mobile Safari?  For example, if I have a scroller and drag the contents it will bounce back when you go past the top or past the bottom?

I tried messing with the cubic-bezier easing function but couldn't emulate the friction in Mobile Safari on an iPhone/iPod. I want to make the HTML page as similar to an app as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with pure CSS3, since scroll easing incorporates momentum physics, not a pure CSS3 easing function.

Comment: Right, you have no way of calculating the amount of bounce / push.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at my answer to the following question -

[How to implement easeOutBack easing in css transform animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699091/how-to-implement-easeoutback-easing-in-css-transform-animation/6076657#6076657)